# Azure Active Directory for securing Custom JS Frontend and Java Rest API

Tags: javascript, java, rest, authentication, azure-active-directory

I've currently got a REST API (written in Java using Spring) and a frontend for that API (written in Javascript using Express) which will query that API for the data to display. I've not gotten too far along in the frontend, and wanted to add in my Authorization/Authentication. I would like to use Azure Active Directory (AAD) for this - we have users in AAD, so this is what we're pursuing. I understand that I can use the MSAL.js library to get an `access_token` that I can then send to my Java REST API for validation. However, I'm not able to find any decent documentation or examples for this specific case, though. I see a some Javascript Single Page Application (SPA) documentation and examples, but seeing as this is AuthN/AuthZ, I don't want to have a *kinda correct* solution, because this is important stuff. I also want to make sure I'm handling caching, sign outs, etc, in the right manner.

If anyone could point me in the direction of some documentation, examples, readings, etc, I'd be very appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: Will be your Java backend send requests to the MS Graph API or other MS API where you want to work on behalf of the user, or solution is only for allowing to login your Azure AD users?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to easily integrate with the front end of your API for authentication/authorization of your users.

For java web apps, you can use the [MSAL4J](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java) authentication library, so that the application can be integrated with the Microsoft identity platform. It allows you to log in to a user or application using a Microsoft identity (Azure AD, Microsoft account, and Azure AD B2C account) and obtain a token to call the Microsoft API.

For more details, please check:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I'd been interpreting the intent of the docs incorrectly. I don't need to reach to the Microsoft API - just wanted to use the AAD for security reasons. In short - we're going to have the frontend obtain a token and then present that token to the backend.